# Why is the list box not displaying the most recent entry in Excel VBA Userforms?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, listbox

Row 6 should be included in the listbox display.

[image: My Worksheet]

But it appears like this:
[image: Delay]

This only happens when there is either a debit entry, but no credit entry prior to clicking the add to table button. Or if there is a credit entry, but no debit entry before clicking the add to table button. All the succeeding entries, will have lag of 1 entry after that.

For example when I add another row of data:
[image: Additional data in worksheet]

[image: Form display after additional data]

The properties window of the listbox is shown below:

[image: listbox property]

The listbox is populated using the cell reference shown below:
[image: Cell reference]

Evaluation of look up values and max values based on Peh's solution:
[image: Evaluation]

Name Manager photo with solution:
[image: Table Formula]

How the listbox looks like (listbox is empty):
[image: Empty List Box]

OFFSET formula with new code returns a `#VALUE` error:
[image: Error]

Comment: how is the listbox filled with data?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ added a photo at the main post. It is connected to the through the `RowSource` property of the `listbox` object. `table` is referring to the excel worksheets in the main post above it refers to column A to D

Comment: well in that formula `COUNTA` counts the cells filled with data. Since there is a empty cell in between, this does not find the last used cell, and therefore counts wrong. You see that?

Comment: Oh right. This part was coded by someone else I didn't notice it :/ thanks.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I know it's off topic, but do you know how to count the number of cells in my worksheet above? `CountA` only counts the non-blanks, `Count` only counts numbers, and `CountBlank` will count all the blanks in the whole range.

Comment: `=CountA(Table!A2:A1048576)` will only return 7, `=Count(Table!A2:A1048576)` will return 0, `=Countblank(Table!A2:A1048576)` will return 1048568. Even a combination of all 3 will probably not fit

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried: `=OFFSET(Table!$A$2,,,MAX(LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A)),LOOKUP(2,1/(C:C<>""),ROW(C:C))),4)` but the listbox is not displaying any values when I do this.

Comment: well did you evaluate what the value of the lookups is and what the value of the max is?

Comment: I'll paste the evaluation in the main post. It shows correct details I don't know why listbox is not returning any values

Comment: well your formula works for me. Test if `=OFFSET(Table!$A$2,,,MAX(LOOKUP(2,1/(Table!A:A<>""),ROW(Table!A:A)),LOOKUP(2,1/(Table!C:C<>""),ROW(Table!C:C))),4)` and make sure `Table` is the name of the correct sheet!

Comment: Yup i've tried that it doesn't display anything as shown in the listbox photo that I just added in the main post above.

Comment: the `#Value!` error is because your offset returns a range and a range cannot be put into one cell. I tested your formula with a listbox in a userform and it worked exactly as expected. You must be doing something else wrong. This definitely works.

Comment: Alright thank you i'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I was able to come up with a VBA code to do just that since I just can't seem to get it to work even if your solution should have worked. I used this: `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Worksheets("Table").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) > 1 Then
    ListBox6.RowSource = "Table!A2:D" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Worksheets("Table").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End If`

Comment: Please ask a new question for that, it is completely different from your original question this cannot be answered in a comment.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the position of the last used cell in column A by formula use

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))
```

You can use that in your `Offset` instead of that `COUNTA`.

---

**How does it work?**

- `(A:A<>"")` returns an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values:
  `TRUE` for cell with data, `FALSE` for empty cell
  So the array is something like `{TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, …}`
- Because `1/TRUE = 1` and `1/FALSE = #DIV/0!` this `1/(A:A<>"")` returns an array of `1` and `#DIV/0!` which is used as lookup vector.
  So the array is  `{1, #DIV/0!, 1, …}`
- Because `LOOKUP` will always match the next smallest value if no exact match is found it will match the last used value in that array if we lookup for `2` (since there are only 1s in your array it matches the last 1, which stands for last cell with data).
- `ROW(A:A)` finally returns the row number of that found value

Comment: Thanks this is a very unusual looking formula. How can you describe the `lookup_range` and where did the `value` of 2 come from?

Comment: @MarcSantos find the explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

I just can't seem to get it working then normal way so I realized there was a `RowSource` property for the `Listbox` object

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Worksheets("Table").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) > 1 Then
    ListBox6.RowSource = "Table!A2:D" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Worksheets("Table").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End If
```